# Why can't I delete data using mongoTemplate.remove

Tags: java, mongodb

I've used java `spring-boot` version `1.5.14.RELEASE` and `spring-data-mongodb` version is `1.10.13-RELEASE`. I am trying to do data archiving.

I'll find the data in master MongoDB by `beginId` and `endId`, then synchronize data into other libraries, finally, I'll delete main library data by `beginId` and `endId`.

```java
public int del(ObjectId beginId, ObjectId endId, String collectionName) {

    Criteria criteria = getCriteria(beginId, endId);
    WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.remove(Query.query(criteria), collectionName);
    return writeResult.getN();
}

private Criteria getCriteria(ObjectId beginId, ObjectId endId) {
    Date endDate = DateUils.getDayEnd(endId.getDate());
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").lte(endId);
    if (beginId != null) {
      criteria.gte(beginId);
    }
    criteria.and("updateTime").lte(endDate);
    return criteria;
}
```

Occasionally, data deletion fails, causing `DuplicateKeyException` on the next backup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using static Criteria function, use Criteria class object as:

```
private Criteria getCriteria(ObjectId beginId, ObjectId endId) {
    Date endDate = DateUils.getDayEnd(endId.getDate());
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();        
    if (beginId != null) {
      criteria.and("_id").lte(endId).gte(beginId);
    } else {
      criteria.and("_id").lte(endId);
    }
    criteria.and("updateTime").lte(endDate);
    return criteria;
}
```